# Dynamically setting class name using ngClass

Tags: angular

I am looping through a list and displaying buttons.

Within my loop I have `job.hasJob`. If this is set to `1` then I would like to add a class to the button. The name of the class should be `job-block-` plus the value of `job.hasJobDetails.statusColour`

For example, if `job.hasJobDetails.statusColour` is `red` then the class name is `job-block-red`.

If I hard code in the class then it works:

```
<button ion-button color="dark" [ngClass]="{ 'job-block-red' : job.hasJob == 1}" (click)="changeStatus(job.statuses)" outline>{{ job.jobName }}</button>
```

But if I try this then I get an error:

```
<button ion-button color="dark" [ngClass]="{ 'job-block-' + job.hasJobDetails.statusColour : job.hasJob == 1}" (click)="changeStatus(job.statuses)" outline>{{ job.jobName }}</button>
```

> Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 16 in [{ 'job-block-' + job.hasJobDetails.statusColour : job.hasJob == 1}] in BedJobsPage@62:39 ("

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can use the object notation for `ngClass` with dynamic property names. Try something like this instead:

```
[ngClass]="job.hasJob == 1 ? 'job-block-' + job.hasJobDetails.statusColour ? null"
```

or build your class object in typescript:

```
getJobClasses(job) {
   return {
       ['job-block-' + job.hasJobDetails.statusColour] : job.hasJob == 1
   }
}

[ngClass]='getJobClasses(job)'
```

Comment: I went for option 2 and that worked a treat. Thank you.

Comment: Actually the 2nd example is a very bad idea. The Method returns a new object every time it's called and it's called every time change detection runs which can be quite often. You should rather cache the object in a field and only return a new instance when it actually was changed. `ngClass` also recognizes changes within an object, therefore it's not necessary to return a new instance at all.

Comment: With the first one I got an error "NgClass can only toggle CSS classes expressed as strings, got null" but I fixed it by using `''` instead.